# OrmLite example from OrmLite site will not compile/work -> Code-first Customer & Order Example

Tags: c#, wpf, extension-methods, ormlite-servicestack

On this site: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

I have started a new project and used Nuget to get the Ormlite SQL Server packages installed.  I then tried to copy/paste the "Code-first Customer & Order example with complex types on POCO as text blobs" example into my project.

When I try to compile I get reams of errors and I am not sure why.  The example does not show which using statements are required but this is what I ended up adding:

```
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer;

using System.Data;
```

So the first issues that came up was that an extension method could not be found for dbCmd.DropTable, so I changed it to dbConn.  This does not seem right, why would I need to change this on a main example right on the download web page?:

```
        //Non-intrusive: All extension methods hang off System.Data.* interfaces
        IDbConnection dbConn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection();
        IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();

        //Re-Create all table schemas:
        dbConn.DropTable<OrderDetail>();
```

Now I have run into an issue I cannot figure out how to resolve.  This line (among others):

```
var customerId = dbCmd.GetLastInsertId(); //Get Auto Inserted Id
```

throws the exception:

Error   1   'System.Data.IDbCommand' does not contain a definition for 'GetLastInsertId' and no extension method 'GetLastInsertId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.IDbCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\wsDAC\OrmLiteTest\OrmLiteTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs 89  36  OrmLiteTest

But this line has no errors when compiling (I tracked the function down using the object explorer and added it to see what would happen):

```
ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance.GetLastInsertId(dbCmd);
```

I thought that with this framework I would be able to get up and running with the Nuget package and example but this has proven to be disastrous.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely using the just released [v4 of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes) which is a **breaking release** with significant changes that requires additional development effort to upgrade to.

Here are [NuGet instructions to remain on ServiceStack V3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3).

In **v4**, db.Save() automatically populates the AutoIncrement Id, e.g:

```
db.Save(customer);
customer.Id //populated with the auto-incremented id
```

Otherwise you can select the last insert id using:

```
var customerId = db.Insert(customer, selectIdentity:true);
```

Here are [more examples showcasing OrmLite's new API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs).

Comment: Nice! Just as I discovered this framework is when this happened.  I didn't notice any information on the main page regarding this.  I hope those examples get updated, in the meantime I will try port it over to v4.....